# How to solve "Unreachable Statement"

Tags: java, android

This is my `Android` code.I have an error in below line `Toast` that say "Unreachable Statement" and I know this error come from `return` of my `If` but I don't know how solve it

Error part:

```
do
{
    return;
    if ((paramAnonymous2Int == 0) && (AndroidHTMLActivity.this.Count == 4))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"نسخه رایگان",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

The whole Function :

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void SaveDialog(final String paramString)
    {
        final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Object localObject = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Details WHERE ID=" + paramString + ";", null);
        if (((Cursor)localObject).moveToFirst()) {
            do
            {
                AndroidHTMLActivity.this.appName = ((Cursor)localObject).getString(1);
                AndroidHTMLActivity.this.txtClip = ((Cursor)localObject).getString(2);
                AndroidHTMLActivity.this.text_Date = ((Cursor)localObject).getString(3);
            } while (((Cursor)localObject).moveToNext());
        }
        localObject = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
        ((AlertDialog.Builder)localObject).setTitle("ذخیره");
        ((AlertDialog.Builder)localObject).setPositiveButton("ذخیره", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
            {
                final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase1 = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                Cursor crs = mydatabase1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Groups;",null);
                String[] array = new String[crs.getCount()];
                int[] arrayID = new int[crs.getCount()];
                Count = crs.getCount();
                int i = 0;
                while(crs.moveToNext()){
                    String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("GroupName"));
                    int id = crs.getColumnIndex("ID");
                    arrayID[i] = id;
                    array[i] = uname;
                    i++;
                }
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("گروه خود را انتخاب کنید");
                builder.setItems(paramAnonymousDialogInterface, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface paramAnonymous2DialogInterface, int paramAnonymous2Int)
                    {
                        strI = String.valueOf(paramAnonymous2Int);
                        String localObject1 = String.valueOf(paramAnonymous2Int);
                        final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("CopyCollection", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                        Cursor localObject2 = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Status WHERE ID=1;", null);
                        if ((localObject2).moveToFirst()) {
                            do
                            {
                                AndroidHTMLActivity.this.Trial = (localObject2).getInt(1);
                            } while ((localObject2).moveToNext());
                        }
                        if ((paramAnonymous2Int == 0) && (AndroidHTMLActivity.this.Count != 4))
                        {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
                            builder1.setTitle("درج عنوان گروه");
                            final EditText input = new EditText(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
                            input.setInputType(1);
                            builder1.setView(input);
                            builder1.setPositiveButton("تایید", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymous3DialogInterface, int paramAnonymous3Int)
                                {
                                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                                    mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO Groups (GroupName) VALUES('" + m_Text + "');");
                                    Cursor c3 = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Groups ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;", null);
                                    if ((c3 != null) && (c3.moveToFirst()))
                                    {
                                        long l = c3.getLong(0);
                                        LastDir = String.valueOf(l);
                                    }
                                    mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO MainContent(AppName,Txt,GroupID,Time)VALUES('" + appName + "','" + txtClip + "','" + LastDir + "','" + text_Date + "');");
                                    mydatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM Details WHERE ID = " + paramString + ";");
                                    mydatabase.close();
                                }
                            });
                            builder1.setNegativeButton("انصراف", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymous3DialogInterface, int paramAnonymous3Int)
                                {
                                    paramAnonymous3DialogInterface.cancel();
                                    AndroidHTMLActivity.this.myBrowser.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:fill_comment()");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            builder1.show();
                        }
                        do
                        {
                            return;
                            if ((paramAnonymous2Int == 0) && (AndroidHTMLActivity.this.Count == 4))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"نسخه رایگان",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        while (paramAnonymous2Int == 0);
                        Cursor c2 = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM `MainContent` WHERE `GroupID` LIKE '" + localObject1 + "'", null);
                        (c2).moveToFirst();
                        if ((c2).getInt(0) < 5)
                        {
                            mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO MainContent (AppName,Txt,GroupID,Time) VALUES('" + AndroidHTMLActivity.this.appName + "','" + AndroidHTMLActivity.this.txtClip + "','" + (String)localObject1 + "','" + text_Date + "');");
                            mydatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM Details WHERE ID = " + paramString + ";");
                            mydatabase.close();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"نسخه رایگان",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        AndroidHTMLActivity.this.myBrowser.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                AndroidHTMLActivity.this.myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:fill_comment()");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });
        ((AlertDialog.Builder)localObject).setNegativeButton("اشتراک گذاری", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                String str = txtClip;
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "Subject");
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", str);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
            }
        });
        ((AlertDialog.Builder)localObject).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void configuration()
    {
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(AndroidHTMLActivity.this, Directory.class);
        AndroidHTMLActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
        AndroidHTMLActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Comment: Well what do you *want* to happen? Do you want to return before the `if` statement or not? Why do you have that `return` statement?

Comment: @JonSkeet : last night my backup from my project are remove and I had to decompile my apk file to get my code and then I saw that my if condition have `return` and `do`

Comment: Well I wouldn't trust that decompiler then... and now would be a good time to learn about better source control. (Github account, maybe?)

Comment: @JonSkeet : sorry.I don't understand what you want.I have a Github account "kooroshekabir"

Comment: I'm suggesting that to avoid having to decompile in the future, you use Github or something similar to keep your source safer than whatever your previous backup strategy was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code

```
return;
if ((paramAnonymous2Int == 0) && (AndroidHTMLActivity.this.Count == 4))
```

You return right before the validation, hence will never reach it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple remove the `return` statement at the begin of `do` block.

`return` means exit immediately so no other code after that line is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Change ur do into this

```
    do
    {
    if ((paramAnonymous2Int == 0) && (AndroidHTMLActivity.this.Count == 4))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"نسخه رایگان",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

It never reaches because u were returning on the beginning of the Do

Answer (score 0):

In java when return is encountered it just exits the method at that point. Once return is executed, the rest of the code won't be executed. Java compiler detect the unreachable code and it will give error.

```
if(condition)
{
    return;
    yougetunreachableerror();//compiler gives error
}
```